# Find whether Value in Object exists within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to find whether the value `roomTypeFilter` exists within an Object inside an array. I then want to perform conditional statements depending whether the value `roomTypeFilter` exists or not.

Below is my code

```
function includes(k) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === k || (this[i] !== this[i] && k !== k)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
var dayValue = this.ui.dayConstraintList.val();
var arr = [courseTemplate.get('dayConstraints')[dayValue]];
console.log(arr);
arr.includes = includes;
console.log(arr.includes('roomTypeFilter'));
```

The first `console.log` returns an Object inside an array.

[image: Object inside Array]

The second `console.log` returns `false`, in this case as `roomTypeFilter` exists inside the Object I want to return 'true' but I am unsure how to do so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btjakgoo/

Comment: `console.log(!arr.filter(d => d.hasOwnProperty('roomTypeFilter')).length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `includes`, use `hasOwnProperty`. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for more information on the `hasOwnProperty`. It's pretty self-explanatory from its name - it essentially returns a boolean on whether or not the object has a property. I.e., in your case, you would use:

```
arr[0].hasOwnProperty('roomTypeFilter');
```

Comment: When I try `console.log(arr[0].hasOwnProperty('roomTypeFilter'));` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`

Comment: Then your `arr[0]` must be undefined. Whichever object you would like check if it contains the function you're looking for, place that at `arr[0]`. The syntax is essentially `object.hasOwnProperty('function/property')`

Comment: Ahh yes, the function this is within is called on two different circumstances, it's initially undefined, but defined in another circumstance.

Comment: Great :) Glad i could help, if you have any further questions, let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to check if object contains `roomTypeFilter` property.

```
...
if (this[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your `includes` function to use

> [**array.prototype.some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
>
> *some() executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value... If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true.*

Here is an example.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    roomTypeFilter: {
      name: 'foo'
    }
  },
  ["roomTypeFilter", "foo"],
  "roomTypeFilter foo"
]

function includes(arr, k) {
  return arr.some(function(item) {
    return item === Object(item) && item.hasOwnProperty(k);
  })
}

console.log("Does arr includes roomTypeFilter ? - ", includes(arr, 'roomTypeFilter'))
```